# JQuery CreditCard validator extend

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am using Jquery Validator 
My challenge is when the user is updating their profile info. but not changing their CC .

When in the update page i only show  4***********1111

So the validation fails if use: (code snippet below)

```
$("#profile-form").validate({
      rules: {
             ccnum: { required: true, creditcard: true },
             exp_year: { ccDate: true},
             exp_month: { ccDate: true}
             }
```

But if the user enters a new CC number it does what it is suppose to.

So my problem what can i do if the user wants to update something else and leave the CC card un-touched.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a new rule that calls the credit card validation method if the element's value has changed:

```
$.validator.addMethod("creditcard-custom", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || 
        element.value === element.defaultValue ||
        $.validator.methods.creditcard.call(this, value, element);
}, $.validator.messages.creditcard);
```

**Usage**:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        ccnum: {
            required: true,
            'creditcard-custom': true
        },
        exp_year: {
            ccDate: true
        },
        exp_month: {
            ccDate: true
        }
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/kqczf/2/

Comment: Dear Andrew: Thanks for the post! Does it make a difference if the field is optional? And what happens if we remove `this.optional(element)`?

Comment: You could try it and see `:)`

Comment: I just created two sample forms and tried them in different browsers. One with `this.optional(element)` and the other one without it: [form1](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/form1.html) and [form2](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4017788/Labs/form2.html). Would you mind helping me understand the difference? Thanks!

Comment: All `this.optional` does is say "if the field is optional, return true if it is blank"

Comment: "if the field is optional, return true if it is blank" But isn't that what optional fields are for? They automatically return true if they are blank whether we use `this.optional` or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you. The `this.optional` check is basically checking to see if the field is blank or not before evaluating whether or not it meets the rule. If you have more questions it might be best to open another question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation: [New thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093971/what-does-this-optionalelement-do-when-adding-a-form-validation-method)