# What does this.optional(element) do when adding a jQuery validation method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

Please see the documentation:
https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

I wonder what `this.optional(element)` does. I created two forms to test:
[Form1](https://jsfiddle.net/Mori/ctLqyzhc/) and [Form2](https://jsfiddle.net/Mori/Lu0nsaub/) — one with `this.optional(element)` and the other without it. Theoretically speaking and according to a couple of comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12756090/478018) by Andrew Whitaker:

> all `this.optional` does is say "if the field is optional, return true if it is blank"

and

> The `this.optional` check is basically checking to see if the field is blank or not before evaluating whether or not it meets the rule.

But in action I see no difference in how [Form1](https://jsfiddle.net/Mori/ctLqyzhc/) and [Form2](https://jsfiddle.net/Mori/Lu0nsaub/) work. Please help me understand the difference in action.

Comment: Form1 and Form2 are not visible anymore. Any alternate links?

Comment: @accord_guy: Edited the question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

OK... so in your examples, the field is never blank in either form.  Either it has a placeholder value, or an attempt at an email address.  The whole point of `this.optional(element)` is to immediately return true if the element is blank AND it is not required.

So if you had these two methods:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("BOB", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || 
        element.value === 'BOB';
}, 'You did not enter BOB');

jQuery.validator.addMethod("mustbeBOB", function (value, element) {
    return element.value === 'BOB';
}, 'You did not enter BOB');
```

Adding a class of `BOB required` would be the same as entering a class of `mustbeBOB`.  Compare that to having a class of `BOB` which would allow for a blank or "BOB", vs a class of `mustbeBOB` which will only pass validation with a value of `BOB`, blank would fail.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Helpful example! That means using `this.optional(element)` is meaningless if the field is required or has a default value, right?

Answer (score 4):

`this.optional` is intended to be used in general-purpose validation methods, which might be used with required or optional elements. It allows them to skip all their own checks if the field is not filled in. If the field is optional and blank, the method calling `this.optional` returns successfully immediately.

By using this, the method can assume that the value is non-empty, which can simplify the rest of its coding.