# jQuery validation plugin not working for checking special characters

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to add a method to check for `special characters` at the same time it should `allow spaces between words`.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("specialChrs",function(element, value) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[A-Za-z\d= ]+$/.test(value)
}, "Special Characters not permitted");
```

Below is my `signup` form.

```
$("#signupform").validate({

    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            specialChrs: true
        }
    },

    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "name is required",
            minlength: "name must be at least 3 characters"
        }
    }
```

The method is getting called but its not checking for the regular expression defined and also can anyone explain me what is `return this.optional(element)` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.optinal(element) returns true if element is optional.

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("specialChrs", function (element, value) {
            return new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$').test(value)
        }, "Special Characters not permitted");


$("#signupform").validate({

    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            specialChrs: true
        }
    },

    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "name is required",
            minlength: "name must be at least 3 characters",
            specialChrs:"Special Characters not permitted",

        }
    }
```

Comment: Element is optional in the sense, can you explain a bit further or show an example.

Comment: The whole point of this.optional(element) is to immediately return true if the element is blank AND it is not required. See below link for details:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093971/what-does-this-optionalelement-do-when-adding-a-jquery-validation-method

Comment: this.optional(element) is not use here as 'name' field is required here

Comment: so if i set required: false, then this.optional would work and also if its not empty right?

Comment: Yes, if you set required:false and add optional(element) ,then your validation will fail and error message is shown

Comment: Why would it throw error message when we set required:false, it should just bypass right. Where would we set a field is optional or not?